# Unable to use element directive correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angular-directive

I am trying to add a dynamic template and compile it within a directive. But when I use the directive to add dynamically it does not show the compiled version of the template I have. What is going wrong. It is a small error which I am unable to catch.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0BalxNnQYVxEd3mAjexx

UPDATE: Changes in the directive string in add() function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller("fCtrl",function($scope,$compile){
        $scope.addertmpl = "test1";
        $scope.searchType=2;
        $scope.counter = 1;
        $scope.searchConditionsNumber = [ "equals","does not equal","is at least","is at most","is between","is in","is not in"];
        $scope.searchConditionsString = ["equals","contain","does not equal","is in","is not in"];
        $scope.searchOperator = ["AND","OR","BRACKET-OPEN","BRACKET-CLOSE"];
        $scope.searchOpts = [{
          editable:false,
          group:"Project Info",
          groupseditable:false,
          header:"NEW-IN",
          illegalValue:null,
          name:"PR_NEW",
          showing:true,
          type:"String"
        },{
          editable:false,
          group:"Project Info",
          groupseditable:false,
          header:"NEW-IN",
          illegalValue:null,
          name:"PR_NEW",
          showing:true,
          type:"String"
        },{
          editable:false,
          group:"Project Info",
          groupseditable:false,
          header:"NEW-IN",
          illegalValue:null,
          name:"PR_NEW",
          showing:true,
          type:"String"
        },{
          editable:false,
          group:"Project Info",
          groupseditable:false,
          header:"NEW-IN",
          illegalValue:null,
          name:"PR_NEW",
          showing:true,
          type:"String"
        }];
        $scope.add = function(){

            var limit = 10;
            if ($scope.counter == limit)  {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + vc.counter + " inputs");
            }
            else {
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.id = "div-"+$scope.counter;
                var elementToAdd = angular.element("<datan-type  counter='{{counter}}' searchconditionsstring='searchConditionsString' searchconditionsnumber='searchConditionsNumber' searchoperator='searchOperator' searchtype='searchType' content='addertmpl' searchopts='searchOpts'></datan-type>");
                $compile(elementToAdd[0])($scope);
                newdiv.innerHTML = elementToAdd[0];
                document.getElementById('dynamicInput').appendChild(newdiv);
                console.log(elementToAdd);
                alert(newdiv.innerHTML);
                $scope.counter++;
            }
        };
      });

      app.directive('datanType', function ($compile) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
        var testTemplate1 = "<span class='mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield input-padding-left'>"+
                                        "<select class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='f"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='f"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='select' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].f"+(attrs.counter)+"' ng-change='searchOptsOnSelect("+(attrs.counter)+")'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Criteria</option>"+
                                        "<option ng-repeat='item in searchOpts track by $index' id='f"+(attrs.counter)+"-{{$index}}-{{item.type}}' value='{{item.name}}'>{{item.name}}</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='o0' name='o0' type='select' ng-if='searchType === 2' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch[0].o0' ng-options='item for item in searchConditionsString'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Condition</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='o0' name='o0' type='select' ng-if='searchType === 3' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch[0].o0' ng-options='item for item in searchConditionsNumber'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Condition</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<input class='mdl-textfield__input' id='v"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='v"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='text' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].v"+(attrs.counter)+"' placeholder='%Search Value'>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='c"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='c"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='select' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].c"+(attrs.counter)+"' ng-options='item for item in searchOperator'>"+
                                        "<option value=''>Operator</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<br><br>"+
                                        "</span>"

        var testTemplate2 = '<h1>Test2</h1>';
        var testTemplate3 = '<h1>Test3</h1>';
        var template = '';   
        switch(attrs.content){
            case 'test1':
                template = testTemplate1;
                break;
            case 'test2':
                template = testTemplate2;
                break;
            case 'test3':
                template = testTemplate3;
                break;
        }

        ele.html(template);
        alert(ele.html());
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);  

    }
  };
});



</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="fCtrl">
  <p>Result:</p>
  <datan-type content="test1" counter="0"></datan-type>
  <div id="dynamicInput" class="test"></div>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add Form Elem Eg - Error Area</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish here?  it doesn't make sense to try and render angular directives in strings and then try to compile the string;  the directives can't be bound until they are in the DOM, but by the time compile adds them this way, it's too late for them to be evaluated.  There are much easier ways to dynamically add content within angular.

Comment: I am on a project with a use case.

Comment: @Claies do you have an alternative for the same logic?

Answer (score 0):

Give restriction to both `Element (E)` and `Attribute (A)`

```js
$scope.add = function(){
      
        var limit = 10;
        if ($scope.counter == limit)  {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + vc.counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.id = "div-"+$scope.counter;
            var elementToAdd = angular.element("<tmpl-adder  counter='{{counter}}' searchconditionsstring='searchConditionsString' searchconditionsnumber='searchConditionsNumber' searchoperator='searchOperator' searchtype='searchType' content='addertmpl' searchopts='searchOpts'></tmpl-adder>");
            $compile(elementToAdd[0])($scope);
            newdiv.innerHTML = elementToAdd[0].outerHTML;
            console.log("elementToAdd[0]", elementToAdd)
            document.getElementById('dynamicInput').appendChild(newdiv);
            alert(newdiv.innerHTML);
            $scope.counter++;
        }
    };


app.directive('datanType', function ($compile) {
  return { 
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
        var testTemplate1 = "<span class='mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield input-padding-left'>"+
                                        "<select class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='f"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='f"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='select' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].f"+(attrs.counter)+"' ng-change='searchOptsOnSelect("+(attrs.counter)+")'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Criteria</option>"+
                                        "<option ng-repeat='item in searchOpts track by $index' id='f"+(attrs.counter)+"-{{$index}}-{{item.type}}' value='{{item.name}}'>{{item.name}}</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='o0' name='o0' type='select' ng-if='searchType === 2' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch[0].o0' ng-options='item for item in searchConditionsString'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Condition</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='o0' name='o0' type='select' ng-if='searchType === 3' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch[0].o0' ng-options='item for item in searchConditionsNumber'>"+
                                        "<option value='' selected>Condition</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<input class='mdl-textfield__input' id='v"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='v"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='text' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].v"+(attrs.counter)+"' placeholder='%Search Value'>"+
                                        "<select  class='mdl-textfield__input mdl-select' id='c"+(attrs.counter)+"' name='c"+(attrs.counter)+"' type='select' ng-model='searchOpts.selectedSearch["+(attrs.counter)+"].c"+(attrs.counter)+"' ng-options='item for item in searchOperator'>"+
                                        "<option value=''>Operator</option>"+
                                        "</select>"+
                                        "<br><br>"+
                                        "</span>"
        
        var testTemplate2 = '<h1>Test2</h1>';
        var testTemplate3 = '<h1>Test3</h1>';
        var template = '';   
        switch(attrs.content){
            case 'test1':
                template = testTemplate1;
                break;
            case 'test2':
                template = testTemplate2;
                break;
            case 'test3':
                template = testTemplate3;
                break;
        }
        
        ele.html(template);
        alert(ele.html());
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);  
      
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div datan-type content="test1" counter="0"></div>
```

This is working fine on my plunkr

Comment: Can you try clicking on the button in the plunker. That is the one not working. The directive works fine.

Comment: @Gary updated `$scope.add()`. if you inspect element the html is there inside `#dynamicInput`.

Comment: Which one? I think you updated that in a fork. I am unable to add sections using the code. Can you check.

Comment: @Gary `newdiv.innerHTML = elementToAdd[0].outerHTML;`

Comment: I can get the directive but from $scope.add() the new fields are not added in. The elementToAdd[0].outerHTML seems to be a uncompiled directive. `<datan-type content="test1" counter="0"></datan-type>` was working always. I need the button to add new form items. Is that working for you?